# CSS cursor when dragging

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable, mouse-cursor

I have a div like so, but when I drag on this div, the cursor automatically changes to the `disabled` one. How can I fix this?

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: e-resize;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true"></div>
```

The div must include the `draggable` attribute as I need it for other usage.

Comment: I don't see disable cursor.

Comment: @prograk Try to drag the red square, On dragging the cursor changes its type from `e-resize` to `disabled`

Comment: The `disabled` cursor shows that you can not drop the block here. You need to define a drop zone. Look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Answer (score 6):

#### 1. What's happening

The `draggable` attribute [indicates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable)

> whether the element can be dragged, either with native browser behavior or the [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

When an element is made draggable using this attribute, the API and the browser control the appearance of the cursor during the drag:

| cursor | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| disabled | you can't drop the block here |
| copy | dragged block will be copied to the drop zone |
| move | dragged block will be moved to the drop zone |

and so on. With [drag effects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#drag_effects) you can define what will happen to the block after it has been dropped, and the cursor will change its appearance over the [drop zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#define_a_drop_zone) to suggest the user what fate awaits the dragged block.

You can also define the [drag image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#define_the_drag_image), but that means not changing the cursor, but turning the dragged block itself into an image :)

In this demo the second block changes to the website logo after a couple of seconds of dragging. And the cursor for both draggable blocks changes over the drop zone as the API and browser see fit.

```js
function imageOnDragging(event) {
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = "https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico";
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
}
```

```css
.demo {
  color: white;
  font: 15px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.drag-me {
  background-color: #369;
}

.drop-zone {
  background: #69c;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo drop-zone" ondragover="event.preventDefault()">Drop zone</div>
<div class="demo drag-me" draggable="true">Drag me</div>
<div class="demo drag-me" draggable="true" ondragstart="imageOnDragging(event)">Image on dragging</div>
```

#### 2. What can be done

You can use the [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) interaction from the jQuery UI to bypass the attribute, simplify your work, and be able to control the cursor with CSS.

Add the `:active` pseudo-class to stylize the block's dragging state.

This demo uses CSS for `grab` and `grabbing` cursor from Ben Kalsky's [CodePen](https://codepen.io/benkalsky/pen/ByJawa). You can drag and drop the block wherever you want.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/YzEyxxb

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable-by-jquery-ui").draggable();
});
```

```css
.demo {
  color: white;
  font: 15px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.drag-me.draggable-by-jquery-ui {
  background-color: #f60;
}

.draggable-by-jquery-ui {
  cursor: url("https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/openhand.cur"), all-scroll;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -o-grab;
  cursor: -ms-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

.draggable-by-jquery-ui:active {
  cursor: url("https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/closedhand.cur"), all-scroll;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: -o-grabbing;
  cursor: -ms-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo drag-me draggable-by-jquery-ui">Drag me wherever you want</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

#### 3. If the `draggable` attribute is obligatory

As far as I can see, jQuery UI allows you to style the cursor even if the block has the `draggable` attribute:

```js
$(function() {
  $("[draggable=true]").draggable();
});
```

```css
[draggable=true] {
  cursor: e-resize;
}

.demo {
  background-color: #f60;
  color: white;
  font: 15px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo" draggable="true">Fix the attribute</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cursor is disabled because you do not have a drop zone specified which can receive the dragged element as Gleb already mentioned. However, it seems that this is not the behaviour you want and Gleb provided already a workable solution.

I found this question while searching for a solution to change the cursor on the drop zone.

For all the others stumbling across this post with the same question I had here is a working example:

```js
function dragoverHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: e-resize;
}

.receive {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true"></div>

<div class="receive" ondragover="dragoverHandler(event);"></div>
```